# Use neural network to learn distribution of values for classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Use neural network to learn distribution of values for classification

The aim is to classify 1-D inputs using a neural network. There are two classes that should be classified, `A` and `B`. Each input, used to determine the class, is a number between `0.0` and `1.0`.

The input values for `class A` are evenly distributed between `0` and `1` like so:
[image: class A distribution]

The input values for `class B` are all in the range of `0.4` to `0.6` like so:

[image: class B distribution]

Now I want to train a neural network that can learn to classify values in the range of `0.4` to `0.6` as `B` and the rest as `A`. So I need a neural network that can approximate the upper and lower bounds of a class. My previous attemps at doing so have been unsuccessful - the neural network always returns a 50% probability for any input across the board, and the loss does not decrease during epochs.

Using Tensorflow and Keras in Python I have trained simple models such as the following:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

(full training script linked below)

On a side note, I would imagine the neural network to work like this: Some neurons fire only below 0.4, some only above 0.6. If either of those groups of neuron fires, it's class `A`, if neither fires, it's class `B`. Unfortunately, that's not what is happening.

How does one go about classifying the inputs described above using neural networks?

--

Example script: https://pastebin.com/xNJUqXyU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things could be changed in your model architecture here.

First, the loss should not be `loss='mean_squared_error'`, it is better to use `loss='binary_crossentropy'`, which is better suited for binary classification problems. I will not explain the difference here, this is something that can be looked up easily in the Keras documentation.

You also need to change the definition of your last layer. You only need to have one last node, which will be the probability of belonging to class 1 (hence having a node for the probability of belonging to class 0 is redundant), and you should be using `activation=tf.nn.sigmoid` instead of softmax.

Something else you can do is define class weights to deal with the imbalance of your data. It seems like given how you define your sample here, weighting class 0 to be 4 times as much as class 1 would make sense.

Once all these changes are made, you should be left with something that looks like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Dense(1),
keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu),
keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.relu),
keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(inputs_training), np.array(targets_training), epochs=5, verbose=1, class_weight = {0:4, 1:1})
```

This gives me 96% accuracy on the validation set, and each epoch does reduce the loss.

(On a side note, it seems to me like a Decision Tree would be much better suited here, as it would behave explicitely like you described to perform the classification)

Comment: You're an absolute hero! All those improvements are essential and very helpful, especially the class_weight parameter is key. Thanks a ton.